# What is the best way... considering performance

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have around 5,00,000 users in my table and each  user is associated with some books(has_many)

I want to display all the users along with their books ....

I wont be displaying all the users in the same page, they would be paginated.

What is the best way to do this, keeping performance,database hits in the mind. What all things needs to be considered while dealing with large records.

Comment: You want to display 5 million records?

Comment: You MUST portion the data to smaller chunks.

Comment: Do you really want to display all users and their books on the same page?

Comment: I would say pagination is your friend here.

Comment: I recommend sitting down with your DBA and making sure your schema and queries are optimized for this. At a minimum you need to use page-size queries from the database. Do NOT request all the results and try to page them from your Rails code.

Comment: Do you want pagination based on number of books or number of users?

Comment: pagination would be on users .... unless there is a better way

Comment: The human-interface you use can make a big difference in reducing the load on the DBM, while still allowing reasonably fast lookups for the user. Use an auto-completing text-input box to allow the user to start weeding out unnecessary results right away. Only allow a DB query for the results after the user has entered four or five characters if you want to give the server some help. It's still going to hit the backend once the auto-completion starts sending AJAX requests to the back end, but you will have improved the overall experience for the user, and that is an important measure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few thoughts -

MySQL is smart enough to handle those many records. You may read all users and their books in a single query and then display them as you may wish. However, showing those many records on a single web page will impact the response time.

Hence comes pagination - read limited records per page. Though this will mean a SQL query per page but still optimized. And of course you can use some query caching.

A better option could be to show an alphabetical list of users, not necessarily A-Z but also like AB, AC, AD and so on. That way your visitors can directly jump to a particular list. Consider adding pagination to it if the number of users in a given list is too large.

I'm not sure how important is it for your website to show latest updates ASAP, but you may also think on generating XML files, as many as you seem necessary, for example alphabetical and generate your web pages from the XML files. You may update those XML files once every 24h. So, minimum DB load.

And please consider building a search because navigating through those many users could be discouraging.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Sending that many records across the network to the machine running his code, plus the memory hit on that machine, would incur the wrath of the system admins, drastically slow the systems, and waste a lot of CPU. Pagination using offsets into the database records is the ONLY solution that would scale well. Even parsing 5 million XML entries would be slow, even if broken into smaller files. A good DBA could help the OP.

Comment: @theTinMan, of course sending those many records to the client isn't a good way to go and hence I suggested pagination. The suggestion for an alphabetical list is to provide an alternate navigation method. I do not think parsing from the XML files would be slow if you have a logic to directly know which XML file to read; you don't need to read all XML files sequentially

Comment: I'm not sure who voted you down, probably someone who lacks comprehension, but your answer is reasonable and thought out, so I +1'd you.

Comment: Thank you for the upvote. I didn't mean to put it on you for the downvote if you might have thought so :-)

Answer (score 2):

It would be unreasonable to display all the users and their books on the same page. There are, I believe, two possible approaches to solving this:

1. You can have a index page for the users where you list all the users. Corresponding to each user you can have a "show" page where you display the user's books. This would greatly simplify the resulting database queries as you need to load only the users for the index page, and load only one user's books on his/her show page. That means no complex joins and not a lot of data each time.
2. If you really want to show multiple users and their books on the same page, then, like someone mentioned in the comments above, you need to use pagination, say load 5 users per page. However, to add to that, you would also need to use eager loading as that could easily turn into an N + 1 problem. You could read more in "[Eager loading of associations](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#label-Eager+loading+of+associations)".

Going back to the first approach, you could even use pagination in that as well; For example, in listing the users or even the books for a user.

Comment: As the tin man stated in above comments wouldn't it be very heavy, if i send the complete 500,000 users list in a single requests reponse 

Even if  i go by the 2nd approach  I would still be making arounf 500,00 DB queries for that page

Answer (score 2):

Queries with large offsets are inefficient in MySQL; When evaluating a query with an offset of `100000`, MySQL has to actually find those 100,000 rows and discard them before it can find the ten rows you end up displaying.

One way around this is to give your application hints: Rather than saying page `10000`, say that it's the page where `id > x`, if you were sorting in primary key order.

It's also crucial that you have appropriate indexes.

There's a good article called "[Efficient Pagination Using MySQL](http://www.percona.com/ppc2009/PPC2009_mysql_pagination.pdf)" on percona.com with a variety of approaches for paginating through large sets.